# Datediff + Looping vb.net and sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have this table containing id and date, with a column diff with different values.

```sql
 ID |  Date  | Diff |
----------------------
  1 | 12/1/17|   1
----------------------
  2 | 12/2/17|   4
----------------------
  3 | 12/3/17|   5
----------------------
```

How to do if I trigger a button, then column DIFF will be updated based on DATEDIFF between date.today and on column Date.
All I can do for now is get the date difference between my datetimepicker and datetoday, this is my code.

```vb
Dim diff As String = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CDate(DateTimePicker1.Value.Date), CDate(Date.Today)).ToString
MsgBox(diff)
```

and to display the table in a datagrid view

```vb
Try 
    Dim query As String = "select * from tblCondition Order By ID DESC"
    Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(query, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    adpt.Fill(ds, "tblCondition")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

can you help me out? im kinda new in vb.net :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following SQL inside the Button click event

```
UPDATE YourTable SET Diff = DATEDIFF(DAY,[Date],GETDATE()) WHERE Diff IS NULL
```

This will update all records having a null value in diff column with the number of Days difference between the Date column and current date.

Change the Parameter 1 to month , year , minutes etc to get the difference in your desired units

Comment: what if diff column has data? 1,2,3 and date today is 12/19/2017?

Comment: It will generate for each column with the corresponding value in Date column

Comment: Hello, I updated my question, can you please answer it again? it would be a big help for me. I think for this one, we will be using loops? am I right?

Comment: You don't need to loop the Query, just run this and it will update the values for each record

Comment: the problem is it will only update null values on diff column, what if i dont have null value on my diff column?

Comment: run without the where condition